# Change size of footer

Tags: crystal-reports

My page footer is set to a size to accomodate 1 line of text.  However as there may be more than 1 line I have set the field in it 'can grow'.  However the page footer does not grow to accomodate the field if it is enlarged.

The field does grow if I give set the page footer to be bigger, but that means if the field is only 1 line long I have white space at the bottom of my page footer.

Having tried the same thing in other sections like Report Footer, they do grow if the fields in them need it - seems to me it is only the Page Footer than cannot change size at the time of rendering - but that it is the one I want.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can't autogrow a Page Footer in Crystal Reports.

You would have to hack your own "Page Footer" by adding in a new Detail section and checking the `Print at Bottom of Page` property in the Section Expert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-report in page footer and place your required field in report footer of that sub-report.